# How much mana does tapping a Forest make, with Nikya of the Old Ways & Nyxbloom Ancient?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Nikya of the Old Ways](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNikya%20of%20the%20Old%20Ways%5d) out on the battlefield:

> Whenever you tap a land for mana, add one mana of any type that land produced.

I play [Nyxbloom Ancient](https://www.magicspoiler.com/mtg-spoiler/nyxbloom-ancient/):

> If you tap a permanent for mana, it produces three times as much of that mana instead.

#### I tap a Forest. How much green mana do I make?

Which of the following answers is correct?

- (1+1)x3=6
- 1×3+1=4

I'm confused about the order of the calculation. An explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nikya's ability doesn't cause the Forest to produce {G}{G}; it still produces {G} and Nikya's triggered ability produces another one. You don't tap Nikya for mana, so Nyxbloom Ancient only applies to the original {G} from the forest and you make 4 green mana.

Now, two Nyxbloom Ancients *would* stack, cf. the following ruling on [Mana Reflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146750):

> The effects of multiple Mana Reflections are cumulative. For example, if you have three Mana Reflections on the battlefield, you’ll get eight times the original amount and type of mana.