# What effects can modify mana abilities and be affected by Mana Relfection and Nyxbloom Ancient?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Considering the following:

- Mana abilities come in two forms, Activated and Triggered
- [Nyxbloom Ancient](https://www.magicspoiler.com/mtg-spoiler/nyxbloom-ancient/)/[Mana Reflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146750) only works with Activated abilities of a permanent being tapped
- Triggered abilities like [Utopia Sprawl](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUtopia%20Sprawl%5d) and [Nikya of the Old Ways](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNikya%20of%20the%20Old%20Ways%5d) don't work with this ability.
- Abilities that tap other permanents like [Urza, Lord High Artificer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUrza%2c%20Lord%20High%20Artificer%5d) or [Heritage Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHeritage%20Druid%5d) are mana abilities that tap permanents but do not get multiplied with Nyxbloom Ancient*
- Effects like [Liliana of the Dark Realms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiliana%20of%20the%20Dark%20Realms%5d) making swamps tap for BBBB get multiplied by Nyxbloom Ancient add another mana ability but do not modify the abilities the land has.

Similar to the way [Winding Constrictor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWinding%20Constrictor%5d) does X counters + 1, versus [Doubling Season](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoubling%20Season%5d) X * 2, are there any effects that modify the amount of mana produced by a source, aside from the mentioned Nyxbloom Ancient and Mana Relfection?

Based off [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49897/how-much-mana-does-tapping-a-forest-make-with-nikya-of-the-old-ways-nyxbloom) question.

Comment: Liliana's emblem doesn't create a replacement effect. It just grants swamps another ability that produces more mana.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Liliana's emblem not being a replacement effect is a relevant distinction. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mana Reflection and Nyxbloom Ancient are the only cards that increase the amount of mana produced by other mana abilities. Some cards decrease the amount of mana produced.**

In order for one card to modify the result of an ability on another card, it would need to use a replacement effect, which would contain the word "instead". So, we can look for cards with this effect by searching for [cards with the words "mana", "produce", and "instead"](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Amana%20o%3Aproduce%20o%3Ainstead). Of the cards we find there, only Mana Reflection and Nyxbloom Ancient increase the amount of mana produced, and [Contamination](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bContamination%5d) and [Damping Sphere](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDamping%20Sphere%5d) decrease the amount of mana produced, and change its type.